NEXT_PUBLIC with empty strings
In my .env.local file, I have a placeholder variable.
It worked fine in NextJS13, but when I upgraded to NEXTJS14, it's undefined.
I tried both:
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH=
NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH=""  //THIS WORKED FINE IN NEXTJS13

I have an API with code:
console.log("process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH(546467468796): ");
console.log(typeof process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH);
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH);

Output looks good.  It shows:
object
object
string
    << this line is an empty string

However, when I try to access the variable on the public (browser) side, it's undefined.
console.log("process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH (41654646): ");
console.log(typeof process);
console.log(typeof process.env);
console.log(typeof process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH);
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH);

Output:
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASEPATH (41654646): 
object
object
undefined
undefined

Any ideas how I can get this to work?  I know it's just an empty string, but I'm using it for a placeholder in case I need to fill it in.
